# Grails GORM save() without flush outside a transaction directly persist data in database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Grails 2.4.5

I haven't activated autoFlush to true in Config.groovy

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class TestController
{

    def testFlush() {
        User newUserNoFlushOutside = new User(
        firstname: 'testwithoutTransactionWithoutFlush',
        lastname: 'lastname',
        password: 'password',
        email: 'email@test.com').save(validate: false)  // Outside transaction ==> directly in database even without flush:true

        System.out.println("User id for user created outside transaction and without flush "+newUserNoFlushOutside.id) // break point the println line, the new user is already in database
    }

}
```

With debug I dig into compiled class and verify that Flush mode is "MANUAL" (not "AUTO"), and it seems that SQL insert statement is directly send to database. As we are outside a transaction, and as MySQL default configuration is autocommit, the insert statement is executed to database definitely (no rollback possible, mysql has autocommited it).

My question is what's happening ?

Why SQL statement is send to MySQL database despite the fact there is no flush of GORM session (I even tried to specify save(flush:false)) ?

Or maybe I missed something about the concept of flush ?

Comment: In what context are you debugging this? I ask because I wonder if somehow the transaction manager is auto flushing.

Comment: You mean which "environment" ? if this is the case : development environment.

Comment: I've just read "hibernate.flush.mode has been fixed : There has been a bug that hibernate.flush.mode setting wasn't used for all locations. Grails 2.4.3 changed the default to "manual", but that setting wasn't used everywhere." => https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v2.5.0  maybe it applies to this bug...